# Guest can't access internet in KVM NAT

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Guests can't access internet in KVM NAT network. Guest can't ping host, the home router and other hosts on the lan but can't access website or ping DNS like `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`

Step to reproduce:

1. On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, I installed QEMU, KVM, `bridge-utils` and `virt-manager` with the following command:
   `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils virt-manager -y`
2. I opened up `virt-manager` to create a new Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Guest.
3. On live cd mode aka testing mode, I tried to ping from terminal and opened browser to surf website like `ddg.gg` and `google.com`

Expected result: I should be able to ping ip and visit site

Actual result: can't ping and visit site.

XML dump of the guest: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/k4Dk2Rxr7W/

XML dump of the default network: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/V47BNYFKwf/

How can I slove this?

PS: I was using this same setup for a long time until one fine morning this problem occurred. First though was I may have messed up some config, but the problem persist after a fresh install so perhaps I didn't mess up any config hence the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created and tested a new Debian guest, and it suddenly works! I think the problem was with the `iptables` package. With the updated version of `1.8.4-3ubuntu2` it seems to work fine.